Powershell: How does the Null-coalescing operator `??` actually work?
I have the following simplified code:
# My "original" Null-coalescing operator
function or { $args[0] ? $args[0] : $args[1] }

function c1 { "code $($args ? $args : './')" }
function c2 { "code $($args ?? './')" }
function c3 { "code $(or $args './')" }

The output looks like this:
Case 1:
❯ c1
code './'

❯ c2
code 

❯ c3
code './'

Case 2:
❯ c1 .gitconfig
code .gitconfig

❯ c2 .gitconfig
code .gitconfig

❯ c3 .gitconfig
code .gitconfig

I just don't understand why the ?? operator doesn't work as I would expect it in the c2 Output of Case 1. It sadly ruins my potential use-cases for the operator for me.
Can someone explain why this is the case?

It fails because $args is never null, not even outside a function. When there are no Unbound Arguments or outside the context of a function or scriptblock it is always an empty object array ([array]::Empty[object]() or [object[]]::new(0)):
PS ..\pwsh> $args.GetType()

   Namespace: System

Access        Modifiers           Name
------        ---------           ----
public        sealed class        object[] : Array, ICloneable...

PS ..\pwsh> $null -eq $args
False

You could index on 0 to make it work properly though:
function c2 { "code $($args[0] ?? './')" }

Or force its enumeration:
function c2 { "code $($($args) ?? './')" }

Both cases would output:
c2     # => code ./
c2 foo # => code foo


I feel like ?? working differently than ? is a questionable design choice by the Powershell team, but forcing the enumeration as you suggested, is a great workaround. Thanks

@DmitrijDrandarov yep, I completely agree with you. But in this case (imo) ?? ($null -eq $args) is doing the correct thing because an empty array is not null. It's the boolean coercion the one that doesn't make sense, for pwsh an empty array ([bool] $args) is false in the boolean context (nonsense).

Another interesting effect of the design I've noticed, is that $false ?? ... also works like that since $false -ne $null. It makes sense with it being "null coalescing" though, but obviously confuses with the inconsistency with ?.
Thought I'd document this if someone stumbles over this post.
